# Elasticsearch wildcard character is not matching numbers

Tags: elasticsearch

I am searching elasticsearch index by using following query string:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search' -d '{
    "query": {                
                "query_string" : {
                    "default_field" : "keyword",
                    "query" : "file*.tif"
                }
    }
}'
```

Schema for keyword field is as follows:

```
"keyword" : {"type" : "string", "store" : "yes", "index" : "analyzed" }
```

The problem with above query is it doesn't retrieve results for keyword like file001.tif while file001_copy.tif is retrieved. `Match` query is retrieving results correctly. Is this a limitation of `Query_String` or am I missing something?

Comment: What does your mapping look like (analyzers, etc etc)?

Comment: @concept47 I am using default analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see your problem by analyzing the string that you're indexing

```
curl "localhost:9200/_analyze" -d "file001.tif" | python -mjson.tool
{
"tokens": [
    {
        "end_offset": 7, 
        "position": 1, 
        "start_offset": 0, 
        "token": "file001", 
        "type": "<ALPHANUM>"
    }, 
    {
        "end_offset": 11, 
        "position": 2, 
        "start_offset": 8, 
        "token": "tif", 
        "type": "<ALPHANUM>"
    }
]
}

curl "localhost:9200/_analyze" -d "file001_copy.tif" | python -mjson.tool
{
"tokens": [
    {
        "end_offset": 16, 
        "position": 1, 
        "start_offset": 0, 
        "token": "file001_copy.tif", 
        "type": "<ALPHANUM>"
    }
]
}
```

The standard analyzer file001.tif is splitting the tokens up to **file001** and **tif**

but file001_copy.tif is not. so when you go search for file its only hitting file001_copy.tif because its the only thing that fits your criteria (has to have a token that has 'file' + 0 or more characters AND 'tif' in it)

You probably want to use a whitespace or keyword analyzer in tandem with a lowercase filter, to make it work the way you want to.

Comment: Any idea why the default analyzer behaves differently in those cases, one time it is splitting on the period ".", the other time it is not?